# Complex Transformation of GB to TB in mixed column using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, that looks like this:

```
  TB    TB2
  4.6    5.0
  6.8    502.4 G
```

My desired output is to convert any value that has the letter G behind it to TB, without disturbing the other values within that column.

1000 Gigabytes = 1 Terabyte

```
 TB    TB2
 4.6    5.0
 6.8    0.5024
```

A member has suggested the following code:

```
df['Partial_Capacity TB']=df['Partial_Capacity TB'].str.replace('\s\w+','').astype(float).div(1000)
```

However, all of the values within the column are being converted, regardless of the 'G' behind it.
I am working on this now, any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Use Boolean indexing to grab the rows with `G`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Select rows containing G
m=df.TB2.str.contains('G')

#Use the loc accessor to mask relevant column, strip G from string and divide by 1000

df.loc[m,'TB2']=df.loc[m,'TB2'].str.replace('\s\w+','').astype(float).div(1000)
    print(df)



    TB     TB2
0  4.6     5.0
1  6.8  0.5024
```